# HTML/JS Button onclick download whole HTML Page for Offline Usage

Tags: javascript, html, download, offline

I have this website I have made, and I have released it and tried it out, but one of the problems is that it won't work unless it is connected to wifi/internet. This is why I want to be able to download the whole page, and possibly other pages onclick. I am troubled on how to do implement this, which is why I am asking for help. Please do not use any php. Only JS and Html.

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on how *Progressive Web Apps* (PWA) work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this:

```
<a href="/test/src/webpage.html" download><button>Download</button></a>
```

This code downloads the webpage, and so far, works for me perfectly. Just found this. If anyone has better techniques, please  share.